# Visual Studio 2015 product key information

Tags: visual-studio, license-key

I bought a Visual Studio license with msdn back in 2015. I need to use my product key after I reinstalled my machine.
I am at the end of the 30 days trial period and can't use it until I register it.

So I went to the link provided in my purchase confirmation email but it's a 404.
I then went to my.visualstudio.com, then in Product keys, but all I see is the following message "There is no paid active subscription associated with your account".
On the "Downloads" page, I search for "Visual Studio", but I can't see any option to retrieve the product key...

I am getting kinda desperate. Does anyone know how I can retrieve my key so that I can register my visual studio and work again

Comment: Do you need the pro or enterprise edition? Community is free and while you could still look for your key meanwhile you can continue to develop with the free edition.

Comment: @Steve that would be a solution but I stiil need to retrieve this darn product key. And I can't seem to find a way ;|